# Why are the days in the .inline style UIDatePicker not being localised when applying a locale to the datpicker?

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I am setting the locale of a UIDatePicker outlet to be Arabic and the preferred style to be inline as follows:

```
picker.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar_AE")
picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
```

The localisation is being applied to the month and year drop-down selection but not to the days of the calendar as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: It's the normal behavior, it meant to be like this

Comment: But in the calendar in IOS the days for the date picker in add an event appear in Arabic when the language is changed. I need the days in Arabic also.

Comment: after i saw SamB answer, i think I misunderstand your question :(

Comment: No worries thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your locale to the `picker.calendar.locale` also, then you can get the weekdays in your desired locale

```
picker.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar_AE")
picker.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar_AE")
picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
```

[image]

Comment: Do you perhaps know if there is any way to localize this label "Time" which is still in english on above screenshot?